# Identify groups with differing observations

Tags: r, performance, loops, vectorization

I am trying to identify groups in a dataset where values of a specific variable differ.

For example, in the data below, I had four patients and made three appointments to see each.

```
dat <- structure(list(patient = c('John', 'John', 'John', 'Jean', 'Jean', 'Jean', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jess', 'Jess', 'Jess'), 
                      status = c('Well', 'Well', 'Well', 'Well', 'Sick', 'Well', 'DNA', 'DNA', 'DNA', 'DNA', 'Well', 'Well')), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Sometimes they were well, sometimes sick and sometimes they didn't attend (DNA).

I can easily see that the status of at least some of them differed between appointments:

```
nrow(unique(dat)) == length(unique(dat$patient))
# gives FALSE
```

I am trying to work out how to identify which patients have differing statuses.

The best I have so far is:

```
# function to find if all elements of a vector are the same
all_same <- function(x) all(x == x[1])

# split table and apply function
sapply(split(dat$status, dat$patient), all_same)
```

This works, but I have a big dataset with many groups (i.e. patients). I seem to come across this specific problem quite often. I feel there must be an elegant and vectorized way to do this. I know I can improve the speed of my approach using dplyr/data.table but I can only think of approaches that split the data and then loop a function over the groups. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non tidy way:

```
table(unique(dat)[,'patient'])
```

gives

```
Jack Jean Jess John 
  1    2    2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

And a slightly different tidy approach where you keep information about the status:

```r
library("tidyverse")

dat <- structure(list(patient = c('John', 'John', 'John', 'Jean', 'Jean', 'Jean', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jess', 'Jess', 'Jess'),
                      status = c('Well', 'Well', 'Well', 'Well', 'Sick', 'Well', 'DNA', 'DNA', 'DNA', 'DNA', 'Well', 'Well')), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

dat %>% 
  # Keep unique combinations of patient and status
  distinct(patient, status) %>%
  # Are they are any patients with more than one status?
  group_by(patient) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  summarise(status=paste(status, collapse = ","))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   patient status   
#>   <chr>   <chr>    
#> 1 Jean    Well,Sick
#> 2 Jess    DNA,Well
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

And here's a data.table approach

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat); 
 dat[,.(unique=uniqueN(status)),patient]

   patient unique
1:    John      1
2:    Jean      2
3:    Jack      1
4:    Jess      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea...

```
d <- function (x) { # test whether each element of a vector is different to the element before
  y <- x != c(x[-1], NA)
  y <- c(F, y)
  y[-length(y)]
}

dat$nc <- d(dat$status) & !d(dat$patient) # status changes but patient doesn't
unique(dat$patient[dat$nc])
```

---

### EDIT - Here's my first ever effort at benchmarking

The results suggest that split/apply and 'table' approaches in base are actually faster than either dplyr or data.table for this purpose, while the 'ch' function is much faster. The 'ch' function does rely on the patients being on consecutive rows in the table, which the other approaches don't.

```
# function for my approach above

ch <- function(dat, group, status) {
  d <- function (x) {
    y <- x != c(x[-1], NA)
    y <- c(F, y)
    y[-length(y)]
  }
  unique(dat[,group][d(dat[,status]) & !d(dat[,group])])
}

# you can also use factor and diff - see 'ch2' below
# generate data with 20000 groups

library(stringi)
dat <- data.frame(patient = rep(stri_rand_strings(20000, 7), each = 4),
                  status = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 80000, replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1)),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

microbenchmark(
  dplyr = dat %>% as_tibble() %>% group_by(patient) %>% summarise(result = n_distinct(status)),
  split_apply =  sapply(split(dat$status, dat$patient), function(x) all(x == x[1])),
  table = table(unique(dat)[,'patient']),
  ch = ch(dat, 'patient', 'status'),
  ch2 = unique(dat$patient[c(F, diff(as.numeric(factor(dat$patient))) != 0 & diff(as.numeric(factor(dat$status))) == 0)]),
  datatable = {setDT(dat); dat[,.(unique=uniqueN(status)),patient]},
  times = 1
)

Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
       dplyr 5523.6048 5523.6048 5523.6048 5523.6048 5523.6048 5523.6048     1
 split_apply  165.8760  165.8760  165.8760  165.8760  165.8760  165.8760     1
       table  224.9030  224.9030  224.9030  224.9030  224.9030  224.9030     1
          ch   10.8821   10.8821   10.8821   10.8821   10.8821   10.8821     1
         ch2  146.2358  146.2358  146.2358  146.2358  146.2358  146.2358     1
   datatable  851.1028  851.1028  851.1028  851.1028  851.1028  851.1028     1
```